# Want to find unique teams where individual is manager or member

Tags: c#, linq

I have a team object that looks like this:

```
public class Team
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Guid ManagerId { get; set; }
   public List<Guid> Members { get; set; }
}
```

A person can be both a manager and member of a team at the same time. I want to get a list of unique teams where a person is either a manager or a member.

Say, I have a GUID for John Doe. I want to find all the teams that he's associated with and I have all my data in `List<Team> teams`. I know how to find all the teams where John's is the manager but not sure how to also include the teams where John is a member.

```
var johnsTeams = teams.Where(x => x.ManagerId == johnsId)...???
```

Comment: LOL! I thought your question is a job search question when I see the title in the list of latest questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `||` to include the teams where john is a member, and also include `.Distinct()` to remove duplicates(**"John is a manager as well as a team member"**): hence your code will be like the following:

```
var johnsTeams = teams.Where(x => x.ManagerId == johnsId || x.Members.Contains(johnsId)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You just need to check if the `Members` List contains the Guid of John. This can be done by using `x.Members.Contains(johnsId)`.

```
var johnsTeams = teams.Where(x => x.ManagerId == johnsId || x.Members.Contains(johnsId)).ToList();
```